# How can i post json with cookies to server with c# webrequest?

Tags: c#, json, cookies

I'm new in c# ,and want to send `json` post to server with this code:

```
var httpWebReques = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"http://myDomain/api/FileCommand/AddGig ");
            httpWebReques.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebReques.Method = "POST";
            using (var streamWriter=new StreamWriter(httpWebReques.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(new
                {
                    PhoneNumber= phoneNumber,
                    TrafficGigCount="1",
                    PaymentAmountRial="2000",
                    PaymentTrackingNo="123434"
                });
                string json = obj.ToString(); //"{\"PhoneNumber\":\""+phoneNumber+"\"," + "\"TrafficGigCount\":\"1\","+ "\"PaymentAmountRial\":\"1000\","+ "\"PaymentTrackingNo\":\"1254\"}";
                streamWriter.Write(obj);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebReques.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

every thing is ok and now want to send server cookie with this code:

```
    httpWebReques.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                httpWebReques.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri("http://www.tclnet.ir/"), cookies);
for that purpose write this code:<br/>
var httpWebReques = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.tclnet.ir/api/FileCommand/AddGig ");
            httpWebReques.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebReques.Method = "POST";
            httpWebReques.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            httpWebReques.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri("http://www.tclnet.ir/"), cookies);
            using (var streamWriter=new StreamWriter(httpWebReques.GetRequestStream()))
...
```

but when receive to this line:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebReques.GetResponse();
```

get this error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

How can i solve that?thanks.

my error:
[image]

Comment: Where does ‘cookies‘ come from? And how do you even know it is a cookie problem?

Comment: cookies come other method,and when i comment cookies line error solve

Comment: You must add cookies that the server sent you. Are you doing that in the other method because you are not in the code you show. 500 server error questions are hard to answer when we only have client side code and no knowledge of the server code or API.